# Ruby on Rails routing error because of my root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, root

I just started using Ruby on Rails and I was following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide
and I was having trouble with 4.3 Setting the Application Home Page. It has you setting up the routes.rb like this -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
 
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

The idea is that when I go to localhost:3000 I would see a message written in my index.html.erb file.
I have no idea what is wrong even tho it is simple, thanks for the help.
~Jimmy

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow - please edit your question to provide some more detail - what did you expect to happen that didn't happen? What error message did you see?

Comment: Do you have a welcome controller with an index action?

Comment: Remove the "get" line and have just the root.  Make sure that the file you are trying to show is in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb (or whatever type of file it is)"  If that does not solve it please post what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

remove get'welcome/index'  check your folder structure of controller is app/controllers/welcomes_contoller then restart your server